# Fastest way to draw a full-screen linear gradient in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, gradient, linear-gradients

I need to draw an animated linear gradient that is updated on every frame, using `CADisplayLink`. Drawing directly into a full-screen context with CoreGraphics is slow, I get around 40fps at full CPU load on an iPad Air.

What's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Why not use [`CAGradientLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/index.html)? Drawing with CA is almost certainly going to be much faster (and use far less CPU) than CG.

Comment: Thanks Kurt, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As @Kurt Revis pointed out in a comment on the question, the proper - and fastest - way to do this is to use `CAGradientLayer`. Add a `CAGradientLayer` to your view that fills its bounds, then:

```
func updateGradient() {
    // Sample random gradient
    let gradientLocs:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
    let gradientColors:[CGColorRef] = [
        UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.25*Float(arc4random())/Float(UINT32_MAX), alpha: 1.0).CGColor,
        UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    ]

    // Disable implicit animations if this is called via CADisplayLink
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

    // Draw to existing CAGradientLayer
    gradientBackgroundLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientBackgroundLayer.locations = gradientLocs

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

---

**Old answer**

After some experimentation, I ended up using CoreGraphics to draw the gradient into a 1px wide `CGImage` and then rely on `UIImageView` to do the scaling. I get solid 60fps at about 7-11% CPU load, depending on how many colors the gradient contains:

Subclass `UIImageView` with `contentMode` set to `ScaleToFill`, then call the following via `CADisplayLink` for a continuous animation.

```
func updateGradient() {
    // Sample random gradient
    let gradientLocs:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
    let gradientColors:[CGColorRef] = [
        UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.25*Float(arc4random())/Float(UINT32_MAX), alpha: 1.0).CGColor,
        UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    ]

    // Create context at 1px width and display height
    let gradientWidth:Double = 1
    let gradientHeight:Double = Double(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: gradientWidth, height: gradientHeight))
    let buffer:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // Draw gradient into buffer
    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace, gradientColors, gradientLocs)
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(
        buffer,
        gradient,
        CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
        CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: gradientHeight),
        CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsAfterEndLocation
    )

    // Let UIImageView superclass handle scaling
    image = UIImage.init(CGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage(buffer)!)

    // Avoid memory leaks...
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Caveat: this approach will only work for horizontal or vertical linear gradients.

Are there better ways of doing this?